# Delete all rows from a dataframe containing question marks (?)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame where some of the values are missing (denoted by `?`).  Is there any easy way of deleting all rows where at least one column has the value `?`?

Normally, I would do boolean indexing but I have many columns.  One way is as follows:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for col in df.columns:
        if '?' in row[col]:
            #delete row
```

But this seems unPythonic...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1a**
`boolean indexing` and `any`

```
df 
     col1  col2 col3 col4
row1   65    24   47    ?
row2   33    48    ?   89
row3    ?    34   67    ?
row4   24    12   52   17

(df.astype(str) == '?').any(1)
row1     True
row2     True
row3     True
row4    False
dtype: bool

df = df[~(df.astype(str) == '?').any(1)]
df
     col1  col2 col3 col4
row4   24    12   52   17
```

Here, the `astype(str)` check is to prevent a `TypeError: Could not compare ['?'] with block values` from being raised if you have a mixture of string and numeric columns in your dataframe.

**Option 1b**
Direct comparison with `values`

```
(df.values == '?').any(1)
array([ True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

df = df[~(df.values == '?').any(1)]
df
     col1  col2 col3 col4
row4   24    12   52   17
```

---

**Option 2**
`df.replace` and `df.notnull`

```
df.replace('?', np.nan).notnull().all(1)
row1    False
row2    False
row3    False
row4     True
dtype: bool

df = df[df.replace('?', np.nan).notnull().all(1)]
     col1  col2 col3 col4
row4   24    12   52   17
```

Which avoids the `astype(str)` call. Alternatively, you might do as Wen suggested and just drop them:

```
df.replace('?', np.nan).dropna()
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just `replace` it as NaN and using `dropna`

```
df.replace({'?':np.nan}).dropna()
Out[126]: 
     col1  col2 col3 col4
row4   24    12   52   17
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check if values not contain `?`

- if mixed types - numeric with `int`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[4,5,'?',5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,'?',9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,'?',0],
                   'E':[5,3,'?',9,2,4]})

print (df)
   B  C  D  E
0  4  7  1  5
1  5  ?  3  3
2  ?  9  5  ?
3  5  4  7  9
4  5  2  ?  2
5  4  3  0  4

df = df[(df.astype(str) != '?').all(axis=1)].astype(int)
print (df)
   B  C  D  E
0  4  7  1  5
3  5  4  7  9
5  4  3  0  4
```

Or compare with numpy array created by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
df = df[(df.values != '?').all(axis=1)]
print (df)
   B  C  D  E
0  4  7  1  5
3  5  4  7  9
5  4  3  0  4
```

- if all values are strings solution can be simplify:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[4,5,'?',5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,'?',9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,'?',0],
                   'E':[5,3,'?',9,2,4]}).astype(str)


df = df[(df != '?').all(axis=1)].astype(int)
print (df)
   B  C  D  E
0  4  7  1  5
3  5  4  7  9
5  4  3  0  4
```